# Slider value doesn't change with script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a sound system and I ran into a bug. I am using a normal Unity slider and a audio mixer which I exposed the parameter of volume. In-game it works perfectly fine but if I try changing it via script or via editor it does change the value of the slider but not the value of the mixer's audio. Does anybody knows why? And if yes how?

The Script:

```
    public void SetMusicV(float sliderValue)
{
    Debug.Log("Have you even been called man?");
    audioMixer.SetFloat("MusicVol", Mathf.Log10 (sliderValue) * 20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where is your gameObject that has slider component on it. try to use `GetComponent<Slider>().value = yourValue`.